# model saving but success and error callbacks not executing

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-model

I save a backbone model, the save is successful.  However the success or the error function dont seem to be getting called.  Here is what I have tried :

```
that.model.save(null,{
    success:function(model, response){
        console.log("save successful");
    },
    error: function(model, response){
       console.log("save error");
    }
});
```

Comment: Are you making a cross-domain request? What's the URL of the page this is loaded into and what's the `url` value in `that.model`?

Comment: Also, have you tried replacing `null` with `{}` in the first line?

Comment: Ok the url: model/pullInfo.ashx/list and when I replaced null with {} the save is unsuccessful and neither call back is called.

Comment: I need the **full** URLs for `that.model` and `window.location.href`, please.

Comment: Yes the save absolutely works on the server...the response was a 200